# Mouse hover using jQuery keeps bouncing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a show content on mouseover and make it stay visible while the mouse is hovered on the list since I am planning to put a button there, but when I do hover, hidden content kept bouncing for some reason.

#### jQuery code

```
$('li.employers').mouseover(function () {
    $('.employer_content').show("slow");
    $(this).addClass("bluehover");
});

$('li.employers').mouseout(function () {
    $('.employer_content').hide("fast");
    $(this).removeClass("bluehover");
});
```

#### HTML

```
<li class="employers">
    <div>employer</div>
    <div class="employer_content">some content.</div>
</li>
<li class="court">
    <div>court</div>
    <div class="court_content">some content.</div>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLdnnxnh/3/

Comment: SInce you're basically just changing a className and show/hiding the elements, why not just use css :hover and a transform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `hover` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Something like this:

```
$('li.employers').hover(function () {
    $('.employer_content').show("slow");
    $(this).addClass( "bluehover" );
    console.log('mouse in');

}, function() {
    $('.employer_content').hide("slow");
    $(this).removeClass( "bluehover" );
    console.log('mouse out');
});
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rbzae0xz/)

Answer (score 11):

You can use **only CSS** to show/hide the contents.
You can take advantage of `:hover` class in CSS.

[**Demo using CSS only**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zLdnnxnh/9/)

```css
.whatwedo {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul > li {
  background-color: #08588c;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.whatwedo {} ul.wwd_list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.employer_content,
.court_content,
.companies_content,
.labor_content {
  display: none;
  clear: right;
}
.bluehover {
  background-color: #01395d;
}
.content {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.wwd_list li:hover .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="whatwedo">
  <ul class="wwd_list">
    <li class="employers">
      <div>employer</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="court">
      <div>court</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="companies">
      <div>companies</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="laborunion">
      <div>labour union</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**CSS Demo with Animation**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zLdnnxnh/11/)

If you **still** want to use jQuery:

1. You are using `mouseover` event that is causing the handler to run when the mouse is moved over the element, use `mousein` instead
2. Use `hover` instead of `mousein` and `mouseout`
3. Your code is not flexible, you can optimize your code as follow
4. Use `stop()` to stop the previous animations

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zLdnnxnh/6/)

```js
$('.wwd_list li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('div.content').stop().show("slow");
  $(this).addClass("bluehover");
}, function() {
  $(this).find('div.content').stop().hide("slow");
  $(this).removeClass("bluehover");
});
```

```css
.whatwedo {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul > li {
  background-color: #08588c;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.whatwedo {} ul.wwd_list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.employer_content,
.court_content,
.companies_content,
.labor_content {
  display: none;
  clear: right;
}
.bluehover {
  background-color: #01395d;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whatwedo">
  <ul class="wwd_list">
    <li class="employers">
      <div>employer</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="court">
      <div>court</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="companies">
      <div>companies</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="laborunion">
      <div>labour union</div>
      <div class="content">some content.</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `mouseover` function with `mouseenter` and `mouseout` with `mouseleave`.

You can see this fiddle is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/zLdnnxnh/7/

Comment: You missed a replace in "Companies"

Answer (score 3):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/15xqsLep/1/)?

You can use `stop()` to stop the animation and continue the new animation from where it has stopped

```
$('.employer_content').stop().show("slow");
$('.employer_content').stop().hide("slow");
```

As recommended by others, use `mouseenter` than `mouseover`

Answer (score 2):

Try using mouseenter and mouseleave instead:

From https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/:

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this
>   example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to
>   Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune
>   times. See the discussion for .mouseenter() for a useful alternative.

```
$('li.employers').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.employer_content').show("slow");
    $(this).addClass("bluehover");
});

$('li.employers').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.employer_content').hide("fast");
    $(this).removeClass("bluehover");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLdnnxnh/5/

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `fast` from your hide function. It is **WORKING**. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zp3jr43u/

The JavaScript code should like the following.

```
$('li.employers').mouseover(function () {
    $('.employer_content').show("slow");
    $(this).addClass("bluehover");
});

$('li.employers').mouseout(function () {
    $('.employer_content').hide();
    $(this).removeClass("bluehover");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the mouseover event gets triggered multiple times. I got it working by using the `.stop()` method before toggling the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/zLdnnxnh/4/

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to have separate classes for each list item you have. Even with these separate classes the code below should get you up and running with ease.

```
$('.wwd_list li').hover(function () {
    $('div:last-child',this).show("slow");
    $(this).addClass( "bluehover" );  
}, function(){
   $('div:last-child',this).hide("slow");
   $(this).removeClass( "bluehover" );
});
```

Note the fact that you only need to use one hover function instead of mouse in and mouse out. This works because you have two divs in the wwd_lsit class and the last one just so happens to be the one you want to target. So be careful with this if you ever want to change something!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `mouseover` with `mouseenter` and `mouseout` with `mouseleave`.

See a more factorised form :

```
$('li').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    jQuery("div.content", this).show('slow');
    $(this).addClass( "bluehover" );
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    jQuery("div.content", this).hide('fast');
    $(this).removeClass( "bluehover" );
  }
});
```

(content class has been added to each content divs)

[See the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o07z8gq/1/)